# ¿Cómo hacer un loop en una columna?

Tags: r, matrices

```
year month   day fivemin rrp_nsw rrp_qld rrp_sa rrp_tas rrp_vic
2009     7     1       1    16.9    17.6   16.7    15.7    15.5
2009     7     1       2    17.7    18.8   17.8    16.1    15.5
2009     7     1       3    17.7    18.6   18.1    15.9    15.4
2009     7     1       4    16.7    18.6   17.6    14.3    12.8
2009     7     1       5    15.6    17.6   16.3    13.2    11.8
2009     7     2       1    13.7    15.7   12.0    11.1    12.9
2009     7     2       2    13.7    15.8   11.9    11.1    12.9
2009     7     2       3    13.9    16.1   12.1    11.2    12.9
2009     7     2       4    13.8    16.0   12.2    11.2    12.8
2009     7     2      5    13.7    16.3   11.6    10.6    12.6
2009     7     3      1    13.7    15.8   11.9    11.0    12.7
2009     7     3      2    13.8    16.0   12.1    11.2    12.9
2009     7     3      3    17.6    17.6   17.3    16.5    17.1
2009     7     3      4    17.7    17.6   17.3    16.8    17.4
2009     7     3      5    15.8    16.0   15.1    15.0    15.5
```

Hola, tengo la base de dato mostrada arriba y necesito crear un loop del siguiente modo:
- Para cada día se debe calcular la varianción de las variables rrp_nsw, rrp_qld, rrp_sa, rrp_tas y rrp_vic y elevarlas al cuadrado. Esto lo estoy haciendo con

```
(Base[-1,5:9] - Base[-nrow(Base),5:9])^2
```

al hacer esto obtengo

```
 rrp_nsw      rrp_qld       rrp_sa      rrp_tas      rrp_vic
5.902250e-01 1.3458064879  1.188557844 1.486095e-01  0.000000000
9.535744e-04 0.0370524001  0.091608524 2.389467e-02  0.012100000
8.881781e-01 0.0000396774  0.249500250 2.654716e+00  6.641083621
1.204225e+00 0.9240976900  1.662990785 1.064281e+00  1.026108221
3.648379e+00 3.7016605609 19.119272208 4.463755e+00  1.139663002
3.477852e-04 0.0052243984  0.003826660 1.024000e-07  0.000118810
1.504989e-02 0.0802866558  0.025638414 3.362840e-03  0.004268009
1.131246e-03 0.0119572038  0.016004780 6.553600e-06  0.007724652
3.311308e-02 0.1140338607  0.393768800 3.501326e-01  0.065484810
1.275544e-04 0.2540149920  0.095048890 1.437471e-01  0.019773984
2.160782e-02 0.0237838084  0.035156250 3.270672e-02  0.029725208
1.406369e+01 2.8553564484 27.696127070 2.903775e+01 17.531052740
2.304506e-02 0.0000000000  0.000469979 8.415279e-02  0.089544578
3.766596e+00 2.8813365025  4.816093594 3.312800e+00  3.524893601
1.682640e-01 0.1548265104  0.364176041 1.544254e-01  0.133006090
```

Sin embargo, yo quisiera que cada vez que la variable day cambia el código

```
(Base[-1,5:9] - Base[-nrow(Base),5:9])^2
```

volviera a iniciarse, de modo que la matriz que obtuviera fuese:

```
year month   day fivemin rrp_nsw rrp_qld rrp_sa rrp_tas rrp_vic  V1   V2   V3   V4   V5   
2009     7     1       1    16.9    17.6   16.7    15.7    15.5   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
2009     7     1       2    17.7    18.8   17.8    16.1    15.5   0.59    1.35   1.19    0.15    0.00
2009     7     1       3    17.7    18.6   18.1    15.9    15.4   0.00    0.04   0.09    0.02    0.01
2009     7     1       4    16.7    18.6   17.6    14.3    12.8   0.89    0.00   0.25    2.65    6.64
2009     7     1       5    15.6    17.6   16.3    13.2    11.8   1.20    0.92   1.66    1.06    1.03
2009     7     2       1    13.7    15.7   12.0    11.1    12.9   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
2009     7     2       2    13.7    15.8   11.9    11.1    12.9   0.00    0.01   0.00    0.00    0.00
2009     7     2       3    13.9    16.1   12.1    11.2    12.9   0.02    0.08   0.03    0.00    0.00
2009     7     2       4    13.8    16.0   12.2    11.2    12.8   0.00    0.01   0.02    0.00    0.01
2009     7     2      5    13.7    16.3   11.6    10.6    12.6   0.03    0.11   0.39    0.35    0.07
2009     7     3      1    13.7    15.8   11.9    11.0    12.7   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
2009     7     3      2    13.8    16.0   12.1    11.2    12.9   0.02    0.02   0.04    0.03    0.03
2009     7     3      3    17.6    17.6   17.3    16.5    17.1   14.06    2.86  27.70   29.04   17.53
2009     7     3      4    17.7    17.6   17.3    16.8    17.4    0.02    0.00   0.00    0.08    0.09
2009     7     3      5    15.8    16.0   15.1    15.0    15.5   3.77    2.88   4.82    3.31    3.52
```

Si alguien puede ayudarme o tiene una idea estaría muy agradecida

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bienvenida Eve. Entiendo que lo que quieres es, para cada columna con datos, sustraer el valor de la fila anterior y elevar esa diferencia al cuadrado. Además que ese proceso se "reinicie" para cada día. Hay una solución usando tidyverse/dplyr.

El resultado que obtengo no es exactamente el mismo que presentas en la solución. Por ejemplo, la diferencia entre al primera y segunda fila de la variable `rrp_nsw` es 16.9-17.7 = 0.8, que elevado al cuadrado es 0.64. En tu ejemplo da 0.59. No sé si esta inconsistencia es porque no logro entender que es lo que buscas. Cuando hago ese mismo cálculo con tu código usando `(Base[-1,5:9] - Base[-nrow(Base),5:9])^2` tengo también ese resultado.

```
library(tidyverse) #Para casi todas las funciones que usaré.

tribble(~year, ~month,   ~day, ~fivemin, ~rrp_nsw, ~rrp_qld, ~rrp_sa, ~rrp_tas,  ~rrp_vic,
         2009,     7,     1,       1 ,      16.9  ,  17.6     ,16.7    ,15.7,       15.5,
         2009,     7,     1,       2 ,      17.7  ,  18.8     ,17.8    ,16.1,       15.5,
         2009,     7,     1,       3 ,      17.7  ,  18.6     ,18.1    ,15.9,       15.4,
         2009,     7,     1,       4 ,      16.7  ,  18.6     ,17.6    ,14.3,       12.8,
         2009,     7,     1,       5 ,      15.6  ,  17.6     ,16.3    ,13.2,       11.8,
         2009,     7,     2,       1 ,      13.7  ,  15.7     ,12.0    ,11.1,       12.9,
         2009,     7,     2,       2 ,      13.7  ,  15.8     ,11.9    ,11.1,       12.9,
         2009,     7,     2,       3 ,      13.9  ,  16.1     ,12.1    ,11.2,       12.9,
         2009,     7,     2,       4 ,      13.8  ,  16.0     ,12.2    ,11.2,       12.8,
         2009,     7,     2,      5  ,      13.7 ,   16.3     ,11.6    ,10.6,       12.6,
         2009,     7,     3,      1  ,      13.7 ,   15.8     ,11.9    ,11.0,       12.7,
         2009,     7,     3,      2  ,      13.8 ,   16.0     ,12.1    ,11.2,       12.9,
         2009,     7,     3,      3  ,      17.6 ,   17.6     ,17.3    ,16.5,       17.1,
         2009,     7,     3,      4  ,      17.7 ,   17.6     ,17.3    ,16.8,       17.4,
         2009,     7,     3,      5  ,      15.8 ,   16.0     ,15.1    ,15.0,       15.5) -> datos

datos %>% 
  group_by(day) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(rrp_nsw:rrp_vic), ~(. - lag(.))^2)
```

Obtengo este resultado

```
# A tibble: 15 x 9
# Groups:   day [3]
year month   day fivemin  rrp_nsw rrp_qld   rrp_sa  rrp_tas  rrp_vic
<dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
  1  2009     7     1       1 NA       NA      NA       NA       NA      
2   2009     7     1       2  0.64     1.44    1.21     0.16     0      
3   2009     7     1       3  0        0.0400  0.09     0.04     0.01000
4   2009     7     1       4  1        0       0.25     2.56     6.76   
5   2009     7     1       5  1.21     1       1.69     1.21     1      
6   2009     7     2       1 NA       NA      NA       NA       NA      
7   2009     7     2       2  0        0.01    0.01000  0        0      
8   2009     7     2       3  0.04     0.09    0.0400   0.01000  0      
9   2009     7     2       4  0.01000  0.01    0.01000  0        0.01000
10  2009     7     2       5  0.01     0.09    0.360    0.360    0.04   
11  2009     7     3       1 NA       NA      NA       NA       NA      
12  2009     7     3       2  0.01     0.0400  0.0400   0.0400   0.04   
13  2009     7     3       3 14.4      2.56   27.0     28.1     17.6    
14  2009     7     3       4  0.01000  0       0        0.09     0.0900 
15  2009     7     3       5  3.61     2.56    4.84     3.24     3.61
```

Explico un poco el código porque las llamadas a `mutate_at()` a veces son complicadas.

- `group_by()`, que define un grupo de datos, en este caso por cada día. En adelante cada operación se realizará por cada grupo y con eso logro "reiniciar" la diferencia en cada día/grupo.
- `mutate_at()` que me permite seleccionar un conjunto de columnas sobre las que haré las modificaciones. Dentro de la llamada de `mutate_at()` el símbolo `.` será el "pronombre" con el que llamo anónimamente a cada columna. Así me ahorro tener que especificar todos los nombres de columna.

  - Dentro de esa función uso `vars(rrp_nsw:rrp_vic)` para indicar el intervalo de columnas sobre el que voy a trabajar. El símbolo `:` sirve en este contexto para definir ese intervalo.
- `~` es un ayudante para definir una función anónima dentro de `mutate_at`. En combinación con `.` para referirme a los datos nos ayuda a definir las operaciones aritméticas.
- `lag()` me regresa un vector "atrasado" una posición. Así puedo calcular fácilmente la diferencia con el valor anterior.

> Si no es lo que estás buscando no dudes en mencionarlo en un comentario. Seguro obtendrás ayuda de esta comunidad.

Answer (score 0):

Con R base, bastante más complejo que la solución de @mpaladino sin duda

```
# Calculamos la el cuadrado de la diferencia por grupo
grupos <- aggregate(cbind(rrp_nsw, rrp_qld, rrp_sa, rrp_tas, rrp_vic) ~ year + month + day, Base, function(x) {(x[-1] - x[-length(x)])^2})
# Expandimos cada grupo en nuevas filas
obs <- sapply(grupos$rrp_nsw,length)
with(grupos,
    data.frame(year=rep(year,obs),
               month=rep(month,obs),
               day=rep(day,obs),
               rrp_nsw=unlist(rrp_nsw,length),
               rrp_qld=unlist(rrp_qld,length),
               rrp_sa=unlist(rrp_sa,length),
               rrp_tas=unlist(rrp_tas,length),
               rrp_vic=unlist(rrp_vic,length)
               )
)

       year month day rrp_nsw rrp_qld rrp_sa rrp_tas rrp_vic
1.1.11 2009     7   1    0.64    1.44   1.21    0.16    0.00
1.1.12 2009     7   1    0.00    0.04   0.09    0.04    0.01
1.1.13 2009     7   1    1.00    0.00   0.25    2.56    6.76
1.1.14 2009     7   1    1.21    1.00   1.69    1.21    1.00
2.1.11 2009     7   2    0.00    0.01   0.01    0.00    0.00
2.1.12 2009     7   2    0.04    0.09   0.04    0.01    0.00
2.1.13 2009     7   2    0.01    0.01   0.01    0.00    0.01
2.1.14 2009     7   2    0.01    0.09   0.36    0.36    0.04
2.1.15 2009     7   2    0.00    0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00
3.1.11 2009     7   3    0.01    0.04   0.04    0.04    0.04
3.1.12 2009     7   3   14.44    2.56  27.04   28.09   17.64
3.1.13 2009     7   3    0.01    0.00   0.00    0.09    0.09
3.1.14 2009     7   3    3.61    2.56   4.84    3.24    3.61
```